# Firebase Images are not properly scaling up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application which uses Google Firebase and RecyclerView. While retrieving the images from Firebease, images are not properly scaling up. When scrolling the recyclerview, sometimes images are showing as smaller ones and  sometimes bigger. They are not scalling properly. I am using Glide to load the images. Please help me .

Also, is it a good idea to use Recuyclerview to use in complex application since OnbindViewHolder being called multiple times causing performance issues. Is there any alternative for that.

Comment: Try scaleType="centerCrop" for that imageview

Comment: It's not working,  I tried. I believe the problem is not with image sizing or scale. There must be issue with rendering only from firebase....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
Glide.with(profilePhotoImageView.getContext())
     .load(profilePhotoUrl).centerCrop()
     .transform(new CircleTransform(profilePhotoImageView.getContext()))
     .override(40,40)
     .into(profilePhotoImageView);
```

This means that you are setting a fixed width and height. In which `profilePhotoUrl` is the url of your image and `profilePhotoImageView` is the ImageView in which you want to display the image.

And don't forget to add the latest version of [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) in your `build.gradle` file.

```
'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. its working... But is it a good idea to use Recuyclerview to use in complex application since OnbindViewHolder being called multiple times causing performance issues?

Comment: Yes, `Recyclerview` is a common class used within Android and Firebase applications.